# Visual Studio "item + item" issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio

So I'm having some issues with Visual Studio

Here's my current issue

```
const char* Char1 = "Foo ";
const char* Char2 = "Bar ";
const char* Char3 = Char1 + Char2;
/*                        ^ 
This is where the error is coming
Here the error I'm getting

expression must have integral or unscoped enum type
*/
```

This is for strings, and ImVec <- (ImGui). My friends have told me I've configured my project wrong. But I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Can some big brain genius help me?

**Forgot to add I'm using visual studio 2019**

EDIT: Someone asked what im trying to do heres it

```
        void newStyle(const char* name) {
            const char* path = "./Assets/Styles/" + name + ".style";
            std::ofstream file(path);
            std::string data("STYLE (WIP)");
            file << data;
        }
```

Comment: the last line is just wrong, has nothing to do with how you configured your project. What do you mean with "This is for int, strings. floats, and doubles" ? `+` is fine for all types you list, just not for `const char*`

Comment: I edited the post, I was wrong. **This is for int, strings. floats, and doubles** was incorrect.

Comment: can you help us? Please explain what you want to do in that line? Do you want to concatenate the strings?

Comment: Sure thing! I should have made it more clear from the start. Check the post, I should have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add two pointers in C++. I suggest you use `std::string`.

In C++20:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <format>

void newStyle(std::string_view const name) { // note string view
  auto path = std::format("./Assets/Styles/{}.style", name);
  // ...
}
```

Most compilers don't support `std::format` yet. In the meantime, you can use  the [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <fmt/core.h>

void newStyle(std::string_view const name) {
  auto path = fmt::format("./Assets/Styles/{}.style", name);
  // ...
}
```

Also consider [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path).

Comment: Have an upvote! One to remember for C++20. (Probably the last standard I'll program against before retirement).

Comment: Thank you so much! I tell you I'm going to love this library.

I'm kinda a noob at file writing.

How would I start using std::filesystem::path

Comment: @Goose See [Filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)

Answer (score 3):

Writing

```
auto path = std::string("./Assets/Styles/") + name + ".style";
std::ofstream file(path); // Requires path.c_str() prior to C++11
```

is a nice fix.

Otherwise you are attempting to add together `const char*` *pointers*, which the language does not allow. Declaring the first argument of the `+` as a string type essentially puts `+` into a concatenation mode, by virtue of the overloaded + operator for a `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't provide a `+` operator for strings by default for `const char*`s. If your goal is to concatenate strings, you either have to define a `+` operator or simply use `std::string`,

```cpp
#include <string>
...

void newStyle(std::string name) {
    std::string path = "./Assets/Styles/" + name + ".style";    // std::string has a '+' operator.
    std::ofstream file(path);
    std::string data("STYLE (WIP)");
    file << data;
}
```

C++ has the addition (`+`) operator defined for types like `int`, `float`, `double` but does not specify one for `const char*`. And as *@largest_prime_is_463035818* states, it has nothing to do with how you configure the project.

Comment: You can't define an operator with both operands `char *`. At least one operand must be a user defined type.